# Sample probability for binomial distribution

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution

$X\sim B(40, 0.3), \bar X$ is the sample mean, and $n$ is number of observations.

I need help in finding $P(\bar X\ge13)$ for a sample of $49$. I have tried the following, please guide.

$\mu=40 \times 0.3=12,$ and $\sigma =\sqrt{40\times0.3\times0.7}=2.8982$ by standardizing I got 
$P(Z>\dfrac{13-12}{\frac{2.8982}{7}})=1-\phi(2.4152922)=0.0078612~$ correct answer should be 0.0084. Please help

Also I am having difficulties in finding the
smallest value of $n$ for which $P(\bar X\ge13)\lt0.001$, where $n$ is the number of observations.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks promising so far. So what needs to go in your $1-\phi()$ expression to make it come out .001?